# use array for loops

Tags: php, file-type, getimagesize

```
//array of image file types
    $fileType_array = array(IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG);

    //getimagesize to determine the file_type of the image
    $getImage_thumbnail = getimagesize($_FILES[$thumbnail_fieldname]['tmp_name']);
        $getImage_thumbnail_type = $getImage_thumbnail[2];
    $getImage_desktop_1280x800 = getimagesize($_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1280x800]['tmp_name']);
        $getImage_desktop_1280x800 = $getImage_desktop_1280x800[2];
    $getImage_desktop_1366x768 = getimagesize($_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1366x768]['tmp_name']);
        $getImage_desktop_1366x768 = $getImage_desktop_1366x768[2];
    $getImage_desktop_1920x1080 = getimagesize($_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1920x1080]['tmp_name']);
        $getImage_desktop_1920x800 = $getImage_desktop_1920x1080[2];

    if(in_array($getImage_thumbnail_type, $fileType_array, TRUE)){
        echo "<p>Thumbnail is an image.</p>";
        }
```

Above is my code to check if the files selected to upload are images, what I would like to do is use in_array just once not several if statements/in_array to check if the file type exists in the array. How can that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check all this values. But the task can be simplified by working with an array.

```
$fileType_array = array(IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG);

$filenames = array($thumbnail_fieldname, $desktop_fieldname_1280x800, ...);
$files = array();
foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    if (isset($_FILES[$filename]['tmp_name'])) {
        $resource = getimagesize($_FILES[$filename]['tmp_name']);
        $type = $resource[2];
        if (in_array($type, $fileType_array, TRUE)) {
            $files[$filename] = $resource;
        }
    }
}
```

This way only files with accepted filetypes will be stored in `$files` and when you want to change which files you are working with, you only need to update `$filenames`.

Comment: what is the use of `$filenames as $filename`?

Comment: You can look up `foreach()` in the [manual](http://www.php.net/foreach). This will iterate over the array `$filenames` and save the current value in `$filename` (usually it is `foreach ($array as $key=>$value)` but since the key isn't needed here it doesn't have to be declared)

Comment: ow ok..and this will work if the filename in $filenames doesn't contain anything right? since only the accepted values are stored?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't contain anything"?  With this array, in the first iteration `$filename = $thumbnail_fieldname`, in the second iteration `$filename = $desktop_fieldname_1280x800`, ...

Comment: I mean since these are the files selected by the user, how about if the user doesn't select any file for a file..lets say for desktop_1280x800..its empty it will still work right? or is there any other solution for that?

Comment: Since you didn't do a check in your code I assumed they were always present. Please see my edit, this should be sufficient

Comment: yeah, it was not there yet cause I was not sure how would it be..haha..thanks a lot!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41128/discussion-between-vep-temp-and-kingkero)

Comment: where would I be adding my the statements if I want to move the files that are images to a different directory?